# How to get "focus" to a specific NSView programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, focus, nsview

I switch from displaying one NSView to another.  But to be able to receive keystrokes typed in from the user, the user must first click the mouse on the NSView.  I want the user to be able to type-in without having to click on the NSView...

Answer (score 4):

There is a good guide from Apple on [Event Handling Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html). See the "Preparing a Custom View for Receiving Events" and "Setting the First Responder" sections.

TL;DR: You have to override `acceptsFirstResponder` on your custom `NSView` to return true and then call [`makeFirstResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419366-makefirstresponder?language=objc) on the `NSWindow` with your view as argument.